# SVG Elements: Able to locate elements using xpath but not able to click

Tags: python, selenium, svg, webdriver

I am interacting with svg elements in a web page.
I am able to locate the svg elements by xpath, but not able to click it, The error mentions that the methods like click(), onclick() are not available.

Any suggestions of how can we make it clickable ? please advice ?

Comment: you can't. click is a html only function.

Comment: Definitely you would be able to click provided you specify the unique xpath of the clickable svg element. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: please share the html so that other can help

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of Actions  or Robot class